# Can I somehow model covariates if I don't know which exact observation they correspond to?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, dag

I have been asked to help with a problem that intuitively sounds a bit like a normal 2-factor ANCOVA problem (although I'll probably try and fit a Bayesian model with MCMC).

There is one outcome variable, let's call it `y`, and two experimental manipulations, `x1` and `x2`, which are basically the configuration of the equipment. They have 3 levels each and the data is fully crossed (unforunately only 3 observations per cell of the experiment matrix, but this is microbiology so it's not too bad).

Now, there is data on another continuous variable, `c`. In theory, I'd like to use it in my model, as I expect `c` to provide some information on an underlying unobserved factor.

I hypothesize a causal graph that looks a bit like this:

```
                                           ┌─────┐
   ┌──────┐                       ┌─────►  │  y  │
   │  x1  ├────┐                  │        └─────┘
   └──────┘    ▼┌─────────────────┴─┐
                │unobserved variable│
                │(cell activity)    │
   ┌──────┐    ▲└───────────────────┘
   │  x2  ├────┘                  ▲        ┌─────┐
   └──────┘                       └────────┤ c   │
                                           └─────┘
                  ┌──────────────────┐       ▲
                  │random fluctuation│       │
                  │(epsilon)         ├───────┘
                  └──────────────────┘
```

Following McElreath's classification of different DAG components, I'd like to close the path from random fluctuation to y, by conditioning on c.

However, the person who collected the data didn't record things properly, meaning I only have 2 observations of `c` per experimental condition, and I don't know which two of the 3 `y` observations they correspond to...

Is it still useful / possible to try and model this?

Some ideas I had:

1. Replacing `c` in each row with the mean of `c` in the experimental condition. I think this is the worst idea, as it means `c` is perfectly predicted by `x1` and `x2`.
2. Sampling with replacement the value of `c` for each observation from the two values in its experimental condition, and repeating whatever procedure I use to estimate parameters in some sort of semi-bootstrapped fashion
3. Something *magic* in a fully generative model where I treat the true value of `c` as unknown, but estimate the distribution it's sampled from using the values I have...?

As you can see I haven't gotten very far with it and have not properly written out anything. Ultimately, I suppose all of these come back to the fact that the only information I have on `c` is at the group level, meaning it's not useful to differentiate between the effects of `x1,2` on `y` from the unobserved effect of `epsilon`. But I wanted to know if there is some way of thinking about it that I have missed, or whether this is futile.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

A sample of the data looks like this:

```
+-------+----+----+-------+
|   y   | x1 | x2 |   c   |
+-------+----+----+-------+
| 0.015 |  3 |  2 | 19.18 |
| 0.014 |  3 |  2 | 38.02 |
| 0.018 |  3 |  2 |       |
| 0.015 |  0 |  2 | 19.69 |
| 0.009 |  0 |  2 | 19.11 |
| 0.021 |  0 |  2 |       |
| 0.141 |  2 |  0 | 20.36 |
| 0.138 |  2 |  0 | 20.23 |
| 0.138 |  2 |  0 |       |
+-------+----+----+-------+
```

Groups are identified by (x1, x2); and within e.g. the group (3, 2), the two values for c do not necessarily correspond to the values of y in column 1, meaning they could just as easily be shifted down, swapped, or in some other way distributed across the first three rows.

Comment: Could you provide some kind of snippet of your data (e.g. paste few rows), so we have a better idea about it? But in general, you can't do something out of anything. If you don't have the data aligned, this means that you know only the marginal distributions and know nothing about the joint distributions. Using mean or random sampling and shuffling would give exactly the same results in here since by sampling you would just integrate out (average) the variability.

Comment: Thanks - I've added a sample and explained the problem. I think your formulation, of there being no information about the joint distributions, is the formal statement that I was missing to properly understand that this is impossible. Thanks a lot for your help.